# Deny all filetypes but 1 and allow autoindexing

Tags: apache, apache2, restrictions

I've searched all over stackoverflow and seen various posts but no luck thus far.

Let me paint the picture: Im hosting a game server for me and some buddies and im symlinking the directory with maps and mod to apache2. I only want the outside world to be able to download the so called "pk3" files but not the "cfg","log" or any other file type.

That part i got working. I also want autoindex to work but no luck thus far. I get a 403 error.

Current state:

```
<Directory /var/www/redirect/*>
    allow from all
    Options +Indexes
    IndexIgnore .. *cfg* *dat *dll *txt URL *log *backup* database
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing FoldersFirst
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Files *>
    Order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Files>

<Files *.pk3>
    Order deny,allow
    allow from all
</Files>

<FilesMatch "^(index\.*)?$">
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

The FilesMatch doesnt seem to work properly (hence the [access_compat:error] in my logs and 403 in my browser).

Hopefully someone can help me with this, ive been searching for hours.

Answer (score 0):

See here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/634996/apache2-allow-directory-indexing-but-restrict-file-access-by-type

You need also to allow index files:

```
<FilesMatch "index\.">
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

because Apache will search for them (like index.html, index.cgi,...) but they are all forbidden. I'm not sure why, but I suppose Apache cannot even check for existence of those files, and then sends a 403.
If Apache can check the inexistence of those index files, he will create the directory index, and that needs the `<FilesMatch "">` Directive, as the index file name is "".

You can find the information in the error logfile, some lines like:

```
client denied by server configuration: /var/www/index.html
```

And because you want that forbidden files are listed too, you need to add

```
IndexOptions ShowForbidden
```

for example after `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`.
There are plenty of options for directory indexes you can find them in the [apache doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/fr/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions).

Hope this helps.

Update: The FilesMatch needs to hit every possible entry from the DirectoryIndex directive *and* the empty string.  If you have this:
`DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php`
then this is your match:
`<Files ~ ^index\.(html|php|html.var)$|^$>`

It might be easiest to set DirectoryIndex and then match:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
<Files ~ ^index\.html$|^$>
    <Limit GET HEAD>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Limit>
</Files>
```